# show timestamp in docker logs info

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci, cicd

i want to add the timestamp to container logs.
i did in my build stage but im gotting aloways the timestamp UTC and not UTC+2:

```
- export current_date=$(TZ=":Europe/Paris" date -u +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
- echo $current_date
- docker push $CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG
```

Please who can help me??

Answer (score 0):

maybe setting a correct/desired timezone in the docker container will do a job. In debian-like containers without timedatectl command:
**ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime**
And changing to UTC: **ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime**

Answer (score -1):

```
date -u
```

Prints the UTC date.
Just omit the `-u` to get the local date.

```
export current_date=$(TZ=":Europe/Paris" date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: same problem gotting utc. :/

Comment: have you an idea please?

Comment: Maybe the timezone you used is not registered in the zoneinfo directory?